# Remove Unused Cells in Arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm usually pretty good about modifying the arrayformula so that cells aren't displaying values when there is no data adjacent to it. But, with these money values, I can't seem to change it to work. How can the arrayformula be changed so that $0.00 doesn't appear all the way down the column for data that is not yet present?

[Here's the spreadsheet to edit.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZGv32uCwx0L92qG4-6xkWIGLPFN8vRVJ1sURS3F5qPQ/edit?usp=sharing) Arrayformula is in yellow highlighted cell.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: that's my first time seeing DMAX() used to get maxes down the rows like that. Very cool!

Comment: I'm curious where you learned the technique, it's not something I've seen used a lot? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is you can expand the computation to:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(1/(1/(DMAX(TRANSPOSE(A3:G), SEQUENCE(ROWS(A3:G)), {IF(,,);IF(,,)}))),""))
```

The formula will originally return an error for zero result, but because of the IFERROR it will be replaced by space.

[image]