# My ArrayFormula is repeating values down the column. Other ArrayFormulas are working as expected

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a Google Sheet that is attached to a Google Form.
The Sheet has additional columns where we are calculating dates, times, or totals for the row.

I expect my spreadsheet to look like this:

| Event | Venue Cost | Staff Cost | Grand Total | Payment One | Payment One Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Event 1 | 78888 | 500 | 79388 | 39694 | Sat Sep 03 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) |
| Event 2 | 4800 | 500 | 5300 | 2650 | Sun Oct 30 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) |
| Event 3 | 4800 | 500 | 5300 | 2650 | Sun Oct 30 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) |
| Event 4 | 1375 | 500 | 1875 | 937.5 | Sun Oct 30 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) |
| Event 5 | 0 | 0 | 500 | 250 | Wed Nov 02 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) |
| empty row |  |  |  |  |  |
| empty row |  |  |  |  |  |

I have a few Date and Time based Array formulas that work correctly adding or subtracting a single value from/to another value.

The Date and Time formulas that are working correctly:
`=ArrayFormula(FILTER($N2:$N, $N2:$N<>"") - 30)`
`=ArrayFormula(FILTER(Q2:Q, Q2:Q<>"")- TIME(3,0,0))`

The ArrayFormula that isn't working is trying to sum several columns of currency.  It sums the first row correctly, but also places that value in all subsequent rows, even if there are no values yet to sum.

`=ArrayFormula(FILTER($AF2:$AF, $AF2:$AF<>"") + (AK2:AK+AN2:AN+AQ2:AQ+AT2:AT+AV2:AV+AY2:AY))`

Add the value in VENUE COST to the Sum of the remaining columns (# of columns reduced for smaller dataset). (table below)

| Event | Venue Cost | Staff Cost | Grand Total | Payment One | Payment One Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Event 1 | 78888 | 500 | 79388 | 39694 | Sat Sep 03 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) |
| Event 2 | 4800 | 500 | 5300 | 2650 | Sun Oct 30 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) |
| Event 3 | 4800 | 500 | 5300 | 2650 | Sun Oct 30 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) |
| Event 4 | 1375 | 500 | 1875 | 937.5 | Sun Oct 30 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) |
| Event 5 | 0 | 500 | 500 | 250 | Wed Nov 02 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) |
|  |  |  | 79388 | 39694 |  |
|  |  |  | 79388 | 39694 |  |
|  |  |  | 79388 | 39694 |  |

If I remove the filter condition, I get a similar result, but with valid values for the populated rows, and the rest of the rows $0.00

`=ArrayFormula($AF2:$AF+AK2:AK+AN2:AN+AQ2:AQ+AT2:AT+AV2:AV+AY2:AY)`

| Event | Venue Cost | Staff Cost | Grand Total | Payment One | Payment One Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Event 1 | 78888 | 500 | 79388 | 39694 | Sat Sep 03 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) |
| Event 2 | 4800 | 500 | 5300 | 2650 | Sun Oct 30 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) |
| Event 3 | 4800 | 500 | 5300 | 2650 | Sun Oct 30 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) |
| Event 4 | 1375 | 500 | 1875 | 937.5 | Sun Oct 30 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) |
| Event 5 | 0 | 500 | 500 | 250 | Wed Nov 02 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) |
|  |  |  | 0 | 0 |  |
|  |  |  | 0 | 0 |  |
|  |  |  | 0 | 0 |  |

I'm new to array formulas, working off the help docs and examples so far.
I thought I was understanding that the FILTER condition would restrict the arrayformula to just that row until there were others (right now, the spreadsheet only has 1 row). That's what has been happening with the time and date formulae.

I also reviewed [Remove Unused Cells in Arrayformula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66532474/remove-unused-cells-in-arrayformula) which seemed to describe my problem, but I'm not grasping that problem/solution enough to see if it applies to my problem yet.

Also, This output is being used by another plugin that is seeing all of these 'new rows' as jobs to process, so I don't think just hiding the value is an option.

Thanks for the suggestions on editing. First post. I'll get better.

Comment: You should provide the most simple dataset to demonstrate the issue you are having as well as the before and desired after (hard coded) as well as your current failed after (with specific attempt)

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables makes **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data, your question may be closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: Have you tried `=SUM()`?

Comment: @TheMaster Maybe I was right? I wasn’t sure if closed was a verb or an adjective describing the question.

Comment: @CodeCamper You were right to point it out. I believe *may be* indeed  would be appropriate here.